# xp_cmdshell queryout is generating a Excel file correctly but with ONE blank line in the middle of the file

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql, xp-cmdshell

I have a stored procedure that runs once at the end of every month.

It generates a few files. One of them is a .csv file.

```
SELECT @Command = 'bcp "EXEC DB1.dbo.spCreateFile" queryout "' + @LocalFilePath + @MainFileName + '" -c -T -x'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @Command
```

This creates the file OK. The problem is that in the middle of the file, there is a BLANK line. I'm trying to understand why that would happen. I'm thinking maybe it has to do with the size of the queryout results? The query returns over 15k records to put in the Excel file. Is it trying to break it down?

Does anyone have any clue. The problem here is that it's extremely hard to troubleshoot this because syntax wise/logic wise, this is OK so I have no clue what the issue could be.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's a screenshot of the excel file:

[image]

Comment: Is there a blank record? Can you share a snippet of the csv file that contains the blank?

Comment: there is a blank line in the excel file. the file has lots of columns and over 15k rows. for some odd reason, 1 line in the excel file is blank. I'm going to upload a screenshot, just one sec.

Comment: there, added a pic to my original post.

Comment: Does the csv file contain the blank when looking at it in a text editor?

Comment: Just pasted it in notepad and the blank line is there.

Comment: Is spCreateFile a custom stored procedure? If so, you would need to post that sql as well. Or better yet create a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Is it always at the same line in the data? Is it possible the last column in the previous line has an extra line break? I seem to recall some kind of export size issue in BCP.EXE but can't recall right now. If it always happens at around the same line, that would be a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was guys.

It's the query that's bringing back a null row.

I will need to take a look at the query. Unfortunately I'm going to hate looking at it because it's massive and 1 value in it is nulling everything out for that row.